# Elementary submodels of $(V_{\omega},\in)$ are equal to it

Tags: set-theory, model-theory

I read that all the ESMs of $(V_{\omega},\in)$ will be equal to it . But what if the ESM's universe is a finite set?

Comment: It cannot be finite. The point is that each point of $V_\omega$ is definable without parameters, so it must belong to any elementary substructure of $V_\omega$.

Comment: An elementary substructure of an infinite structure can't be finite, because the property of being infinite is first-order, and the property of being isomorphic to a given finite structure even more so (by a single sentence).

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** If $M\prec N$, and $x\in N$ is a definable element, then $x\in M$. Prove, by induction, that every element of $V_\omega$ is definable.

Comment: Thanks. Induction over what? Isn't the following enough?$(V_{\omega},\in)\models \forall x\in V_{\omega}~  \exists n<\omega~ [x\in V_{n}]$

Comment: Induction over $\in$, that is assume that for all $y\in x$ is definable, then use the fact that $x$ is finite to write a formula defining $x$. As for the second part of your comment, I don't really understand why that would be possible (it might be, but it seems to me that it would amount to the above induction).

Comment: Would that do: base-case)For $x=\varnothing$, $N\models \forall y\in V_{\omega} [ y\nsubseteq x]$ n-th)assume true $N\models \phi(x)=\phi(y_{1})\wedge...\wedge \phi(y_{n})$ n+1) $N\models \phi(x)~ iff ~N\models \phi(y_{1})\wedge...\wedge \phi(y_{n}) \wedge N\models \phi(y_{n+1})$. If not, can you help.

Comment: Not quite. Think how you would define over $\Bbb N$, with $0$ and $s(\bullet)$ as a successor operation, the set $\{0,1,2\}$. What would be its definition?

Comment: $0=\varnothing, 1=s(0)=\varnothing \cup \{ \varnothing \}$ so $N\models \forall y\in \mathbb{N}/\{0\} \exists! x\in \mathbb{N} [s(x)=y]$. So $N\models \forall y\in V_{\omega}/\{\varnothing\} \exists! n<\omega [y\in V_{n}]\wedge [k<n (y\notin V_{k})] $.  Is that what you meant? If not can you provide me a complete answer for "every element of Vω is definable."

Comment: No. Forget ordinals, and forget $V_\omega$ for a moment. You have $\Bbb N$ with $0$ as a constant and the successor function $s$. How do you write the definition for the set $\{0,1,2\}$ in that language? (Also, I don't want to give you the answer. I want you to find it on your own.)