# every element of $V_{\omega}$ is definable

Tags: set-theory, model-theory

My attempt by $\in$-induction. I am trying find formula that will work:
$N=(V_{\omega},\in)\models rank(\varnothing) =0<\omega$

Assume,given $x\in V_\omega$ that $\forall y\in x$ are definable too $N\models rank(y)<\omega$. Then since $x\in V_\omega$, $|x|<\omega\Rightarrow x$ is finite $\Rightarrow rank(x)=rank(y_{1})+...+rank(y_{n})<\omega$. Is the last equality valid i.e. $rank(x)=rank(y_{1})+...+rank(y_{n})$?

thanks

Comment: No, rank is not linear at all.

Comment: any suggestion on what formula I could use?

Comment: You ignored my last comment from your previous question, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/623469/elementary-submodels-of-v-omega-in-are-equal-to-it#comment1315252_623483

Comment: Sorry,I didn't ignore it, I simply didn't post my attempts. So I think $0,1,2,\in \{0,1,2\}$ iff $(\mathbb{N},0,succ())\models (1=s(0))\wedge (2=s(1))$.

Comment: Yes, and how would you show that the set $\{0,1,2\}$ is *definable*? Can you write a formula which explicitly defines it?

Comment: Do you know what does it mean to define a set? It means that there is a formula with a free variable, $\varphi(x)$ such that $u\in A\iff N\models\varphi(u)$.

Comment: yes I know,I am just trying to replace > with succ in $\phi=[\exists x,y(x=s(0)\wedge y=s(1)] \wedge [\not \exists z(z=s(k))\wedge k>2]$

Comment: Let me help you, there shouldn't be any quantifiers in this formula.

Comment: $\phi=u=0\vee s(0)\vee u=s^2(0)  $

Comment: I think this what you were hinting to: $V_{u}\in V_{\omega}=\bigcup_{\alpha<\omega}V_{\alpha}$ iff $(V_{\omega},\in)\models V_u\in V_{u+1}$

Comment: No, what I'm hinting is that if $x$ is in $V_\omega$, and for every $y\in x$ there is some $\varphi_y(u)$ defining $y$, then you can use those to define $x$.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to show that every element of $V_\omega$ is definable in $V_\omega$ without parameters -- that is, for every $x\in V_\omega$ there is a $\phi(y)$, with at most $y$ free, such that $x = \{y: V_\omega\vDash \phi(y)\}$ -- we can argue as follows.

Since $V_0$ contains no elements, it's trivial that every element of $V_0$ is definable. So, suppose this is true of $V_n$. Now consider $x\in V_{n+1}$. By definition of $V_{n+1}$, $x\subseteq V_n$, and since $x\in V_\omega$, $x$ is finite -- for definiteness, we can let $x = \{y_0,...,y_m\}$. Clearly, $y_0,...,y_m$ are in $V_n$, and so by our induction hypothesis they are all definable -- for definiteness, we can let $y_0 = \{y: V_\omega\vDash \phi_0(y)\}$, ..., $y_m = \{y: V_\omega\vDash \phi_m(y)\}$. Now, consider the following formula:

(*) $\Psi(z) = ``z = \{y: \phi_0(y)\}\vee,...,\vee z =\{y: \phi_m(y)\}"$

Since $V_\omega$ is transitive, it is straightforward to show that $x = \{z: V_\omega\vDash \Psi(z)\}$, as required.

Comment: Do we need to come-up with a specific $\phi(y)$ ?

Comment: No, we don't have to -- in order for $x$ to be definable, it suffices that some formula or other defines it, we need not come up with a specific one. However, we can recursively specify a canonical definition of each element of $V_\omega$. For instance, $x\not= x$ can be the canonical definition of $\emptyset$ and then given canonical definitions of $y_0,...,y_m$ we can obtain a canonical definition of $x$ along the lines of (*).

Answer (score 3):

Let $N$ be an arbitrary structure of an arbitrary language. Recall that $n\in N$ is called *definable* (without parameters) if there exists a formula $\varphi(x)$ such that $N\models\varphi(u)\iff u=n$.

We want to show that in $V_\omega$ in the language including only $\in$, every element is definable. We do this by $\in$-induction:

Suppose that $x$ is such that for all $y\in x$, $y$ is definable. Then for every such $y$ there is some formula defining it, $\varphi_y$. We can therefore define $x$ to be the unique set whose elements are defined by one of these $\varphi_y$'s. That is: $$\varphi_x(u):=\forall v(v\in u\leftrightarrow\bigvee_{y\in x}\varphi_y(v))$$

The disjunction occur in the meta-theory, where we know that $x$ is finite, and what are its elements. Therefore there is no circularity arguments here.